# Reports in a Client-Server Hybrid Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc-5, report

I'm in a Software Development Team. We would like to create an hybrid client-server application with reports using C# and .NET. It's going to have a WPF client app and a Web client app. Each client app need to have a viewer to show reports that use a big amount of data. We prefer to keep the reports in the server-side.

What Reporting Suite it is recommended for this type of applications?

**Edit:**

I have used XtraReports (DevExpress Reporting) with WCF services but when I have big amount of data in the report, the document viewer have an error that says "OutOfMemory". This error is because the document viewer use the RAM to load the report. It's happen with any document viewer of DevExpress.

I researched for Crystal Reports in this type of application because it is the most powerful, but they said that a RAS (Report Application Server) is needed. The RAS is available in Crystal Reports Server and others SAP Enterprise programs.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a read on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Dashsa, I haven't tried SSRS. Right now, I'm going to try it.

Comment: Hi Dashsa, SSRS seems working great for me. Thank you!